# DNS failover cache in-case DNS lookup fails - AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-elb, dnsmasq

I have a system where all incoming requests are routed to an AWS elastic load balancer (ELB). This requires a a DNS name lookup on the ELB URL for every request. We know that the ELB returns a different IP every time (round robins a couple of IP addresses) so I can't really cache the IP address and the use it till TTL.

However, sometimes these DNS lookups would fail and we want to use the cache only when that happens. Please note that the cache needs to be updated always so when we do fall back to the cache, it's not an old cached entry.

What's the best way to do this? Can we use dnsmasq somehow?

Comment: were you able to solve it somehow? We need to implement something similar

Answer (score 1):

Please rethink your design. If your DNS queries are failing, then you have a networking problem. Load Balancers are designed (usually) to provide high availability and fault tolerance.

DNS Servers cache entries by design (which is different than your goal). This is controlled by the TTL field, however, lots of DNS Servers ignore this value.

If you DNS queries are failing, how are you going to determine the load balancers IP address? Figure out why your DNS queries are failing and let the load balancers do the job that they are designed for.

Amazon load balancers do not have static IP addresses. The word "Elastic" in Elastic Load Balancer means that they load balancers scale in two directions: ScaleUp (bigger instances) and ScaleOut (more instances). Of course when traffic is down, they do the reverse (ScaleDown and ScaleIn).

Comment: To clarify this. This is an intermittent DNS failure issue and our traffic is pretty high so this is very possible. This is one AWS component to another so if there's a networking issue, it's within AWS. The request volume is pretty high so we can have a secondary cache that keeps updating whenever a call to .2 IP addresses in the VPC fail, we want to be able to use the cached IP address for mitigation.